# popViewController very slow when returning to a UITableViewController after rotating device

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a main menu that is a UITableViewController.  If the phone is in portrait mode and then I go to another viewController and then I rotate the phone to landscape, and then tap the back button to return to the UITableViewController, then there is about a 2 second lag (on an iPhone 5) before returning. The lag is about 4 seconds on an iPhone 4s.

UPDATE:
The profiler shows that the time is being spent in a system function, `[UITableViewCell setFrame:]`. The majority of time in that function is in `[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveLayoutEngineDidChange]`.

UPDATE 2: More digging shows me that the culprit is AutoLayout. Turning off AutoLayout completely solves the performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xcode's Time Profiler in Build -> Profile to see what's causing the lag.  It's almost certainly in some code you've written.  Tutorial here: http://blancer.com/tutorials/flex/78335/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in/

Answer (score 1):

The slowness was caused by AutoLayout. The cells in my table were custom UITableViewCells that were laid out using AutoLayout constraints.

Turning off AutoLayout and using the old struts and springs system completely fixed the slowness.